# Why is corner preferred over curve for racing tracks?

Tags: word-usage

For example in car racing, the non-straight parts of the track are almost always called **corners**, even though many of them are very far from the typical (point-like) corner of a rectangle.

Merriam-Webster gives the following relevant meaning of [curve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curve)

> a smooth, rounded line, shape, path, etc.

and the following meanings for [corner](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corner)

> 1) the point or area where two lines, edges, or sides of something
>   meet
>
> 2) the place where two streets or roads meet
>
> 3) a curve in a road

This suggests that the two are in principle interchangeable, although I suppose that corner goes back to point-like intersections, whereas curve is more appropriate for extended intersections.

Comment: Maybe it is because at the speed racing cars travel at, those curves feel like corners.

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessarily true. There are many courses/tracks where **curve** is used to describe these bends.

[image: Suzuka map from Wikipedia]

Suzuka in Japan has many corners which are called 'curves'.

[image: Map of Silverstone from Ferrari]

The most famous Formula 1 track of all, Silverstone, also has 'curves' (and 'corners').

Even in Italian for Monza, 'curva' is used:

[image: Monza map from Wikipedia]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In Silverstone, I see two curves, the rest is corners (I said preferred in the title, not exclusive). Monza does not really count, because I was asking about English (in German, we always use "Kurve"). However, I can't remember an incidence where the commentator (Sky, BBC) used curve instead of corner. Moreover, we use the expressions "take a corner", "cornering speed", etc.

Comment: Colloquially, corner is probably used because "corner" sounds more extreme (it has connotations of sharpness like you mentioned in your original post). Imagine going at high speeds around a 90 degree corner, vs. a slow gentle curve.

Comment: The *name* might have "curve" in it, but it is still a "corner". Suzuka's S-curves are corners 3 to 7.